# setActionView deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

Bellow code works fine but it gives me setActionView and getActionView is deprecated

```
     val item = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_mini_basket)
     MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item,R.layout.toolbar_mini_basket_layout)
     val toolbarLayout = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item)
```

android developer site says " This method was deprecated in API level 26.1.0. Use setActionView(int) directly. "
I managed to fix getActionView but have no idea about setActionView it only takes one argument.

```
     val item = menu?.findItem(R.id.action_mini_basket)
     MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item,R.layout.toolbar_mini_basket_layout) //??
     val toolbarLayout = item.actionView as RelativeLayout
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item,R.layout.toolbar_mini_basket_layout);
```

to

```
 item.setActionView(R.layout.toolbar_mini_basket_layout);
```

`Compat` version isn't needed anymore if you are using `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android documentation you indeed need to use `setActionView(int)`.
In this case the parameter is the layout resource you want to use.

So it will be:

```
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(R.layout.toolbar_mini_basket_layout)
```

Comment: `setActionView` taking only @IntRes argument isn't static and `MenuItemCompat` don't have such method

Comment: No, it is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's not static, it should be on item